# Docker: How to share the same application code between multiple containers/services (e.g. PHP-FPM and NGINX)

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, docker-multi-stage-build

## tl;dr

- application code requires a build-step (pull in dependecies)
- multiple containers need the same "built" code

**Q: what's a good strategy / workflow to archive that with docker / docker-compose.**

## Long

We're in the process of dockerizing a PHP application with mutiple components (containers/services), e.g.

- Worker nodes (PHP processes kept alive via supervisor)
- Scheduler (governing the workers and running recurring tasks in cron)
- PHP-FPM/Nginx (web interface)

The services are defined in a docker-compose file.
During development, we're mounting the application code via volume from a directory on the host in each container,
so that we see the changes "immediately" in each service ([Example](https://www.pascallandau.com/blog/php-php-fpm-and-nginx-on-docker-in-windows-10/#docker-compose)). Life was good.

We are now setting up a CI/CD environment based on Jenkins that should build (+ test) the containers and 
push the to the registry afterwards. Since the "mount from host" is no longer possible, I'm now wondering
what the best way is to bring the application code in each container.

Two things in our setup make this imho particularly complicated:

1. we have multiple containers that need the same application code
2. the "build-artifact" is not a single, self-container binary (as we would have e.g. with go)
   but "all of our code + the installed dependecies" ==> "a lot of files" (slow...)
3. there is a build step involved that requires software that is not needed in the final image

The solution for "3." is usually: Use multi stage builds. We do that. But: all the examples out there
seem to assume the built code will only be used in one other container (which isn't true in our case, see 1.)

### What we currently do

- folder structure

```
application-code/
  .docker/
    builder/
      Dockerfile
    php-fpm/
      Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
  build.sh
  index.php
```

- introduce an additional "builder" container that "builds" the application 
  (gets "all" application code as build context; runs "composer install")

```
# ./builder/Dockerfile
COPY ./ /codebase
RUN cd /codebase && composer install
```

- "copy" from this builder in each container that needs the application code, e.g. via

```
# ./php-fpm/Dockerfile
ARG APP_CODE_PATH="/var/www/current"
COPY --from=builder --chown=www-data /codebase ${APP_CODE_PATH}
```

- orchestrated via docker-compose

```
# ./docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  builder-ci:
    image: builder
    build:
      # ../ contains the "raw" application code
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./.docker/builder/Dockerfile

    php-fpm:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./php-fpm/Dockerfile
        args:
          - APP_CODE_PATH=/var/www/current
```

- build via

```
# build.sh
## build builder
docker-compose -f ./.docker/docker-compose.yml --project-directory ./.docker build builder
## build the rest
docker-compose -f ./.docker/docker-compose.yml --project-directory ./.docker build --parallel
```

#### Pro

- "smaller" images (php-fpm won't have composer installed)
- application code is only build once and then copied over

#### Contra

- the builder container serves no other purpose but to "built" ==> doesn't feel clean
- building the "builder" has to be done before any other container is built

  - that means we have an additional

### Alternatives

- don't use a builder container but "incorporate" the build step in e.g. the "Scheduler" container 
  by using multi-stage builds (so we don't end up with composer in the final image)

  - get's rid of "builder" - but now all other services depend on "Scheduler" ==> feels even more dirty
- use a volume to share the code

  - we don't have to "copy" files in images but can simply "mount the volume" ==> feels "clean" / no "duplication of files"
    (I first thought that this is a really good approach...)
  - BUT:
  - you can't populate volumes during build, so you need to "run" the container in order to get the appliaction code "in" the container
    ==> we suddenly not only have a builder container but we also need to "run" it to populate the volume
  - the containers are not "self contained" any more, i.e. pulling "just the Scheduler" from the registry won't work - 
    we MUST also have the volume in place AND it has to be populated by the builder ==> orchestration becomes more complicated
  - the volume is not ephemeral, i.e. it will contain "old" application code until it is refreshed ==> this might lead to
    confusion and unexpected behavior

### Links

- [Can containers share a framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566244/can-containers-share-a-framework/41576040#41576040) (related question)
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14080 (mountined volumes during build is not supported)
- https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/ (builder pattern vs multi stage build)

Answer (score 0):

Worrying about the number of steps should not be a discussion. What you should worry about is whether the image contains what you need, without any noise.

One of the things your builder method clearly lacks is that you are pushing the codebase towards production even though you ran composer with just `install`. In order to get a production grade codebase into production you would at least need to run `composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev -o` to:

- drop files excluded in the `.gitattributes` by using `--prefer-dist` (this is default since composer stable)
- by excluding downloading of require-dev with `--no-dev`
- by optimizing the autoloader files with `-o`

This command is completely different from the one used to run your tests on.

A default pipeline when working with containerising your codebase would be:

- **build:** checkout, composer install and allow for re-use in following steps or create a "testing image"
- **test:** run the tests and either include or separate coverage out (into a simultaneous step)
- **prepare:** re-use build files and run composer install with necessary production flags
- **image**: create image from previous step

I personally think answers to your question are highly opinionated. Maybe my approach, used working with kubernetes, helps.

Comment: Nah, we don't just run composer install - I just stuck to the essential parts to make my point ;) Btw. current use case is CI, so `--no-dev` wouldn't allow us to run tests.
"I personally think answers to your question are highly opinionated." => is totally fine. I don't expect that there's "the" way. Regarding your answer: Where does the "build" happen? Dedidcated image just for building? "re-use build files" ==> "how?" via `COPY --from`? Volume? Piping an archive to stdout (e.g. "Pipes & filters" from https://matthiasnoback.nl/2017/04/docker-build-patterns/ )